# Django: Cant seem to access specific template with correct user status

Tags: python, django-models, django-views, frontend, django-authentication

trying out making web application with Django. along the process I encounter an error with authenticating the user or maybe somewhere in it. the problem is even though the user has an approved status in the database, when trying to login the user information instead of redirecting to the main.html after clicking the login button the page just reloads. I cant seem to know where I got it wrong because the admin account checker seems to work

in my view:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from .models import Agents
from django.core.mail import send_mail

def main(request):
    return render(request, 'main.html')

def signup_or_signin(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if 'signup' in request.POST:
            # Handle Signup
            insurance_name = request.POST['insurance_name']
            full_name = request.POST['full_name']
            username = request.POST['username']
            email = request.POST['email']
            password = request.POST['password']

            # Check if the username is already taken
            if Agents.objects.filter(username=username).exists():
                messages.error(request, 'Username is already taken. Please choose a different username.')
                return redirect('signup_or_signin')  # Redirect back to the signup page

            # Create a new agent instance
            agent = Agents(
                insurance_name=insurance_name,
                full_name=full_name,
                username=username,
                email=email,
                password=password,
                status='pending'  # Set the status to pending for approval
            )

            # Save the agent to the database
            agent.save()

            messages.success(request, 'Account created successfully. Your account is pending approval.')

            return redirect('signup_or_signin')  # Redirect back to the signup page or any other page you want

        elif 'signin' in request.POST:
            username = request.POST['username']
            password = request.POST['password']

            if username == 'admin' and password == 'admin':
                return redirect('admin_dash')  # Redirect to the admin_dash page

            user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)

            if user is not None:
                if user.status == 'approved':
                    login(request, user)
                    messages.success(request, 'Logged in successfully.')
                    return redirect('insuuser:main')
                elif user.status == 'pending':
                    messages.info(request, 'Your account is pending approval. You can log in once approved.')
                else:
                    messages.error(request, 'Your account has been denied.')
            else:
                messages.error(request, 'Invalid login credentials.')

    return render(request, 'signup_or_signin.html')
```

my model for this:

```
class Agents(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)  # This is an auto-incrementing primary key field
    insurance_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField()
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10, default="pending")
```

my urls:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.signup_or_signin, name='signup_or_signin'),
    path('main/', views.main, name='main'),
]
```

the form in signup_or_signin.html:

```
<form class="sign-in-form" method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <h2 class="title">Sign in</h2>
            <div class="input-field">
                <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="username" required/>
            </div>
            <div class="input-field">
                <i class="fas fa-lock"></i>
                <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" required/>
                <i class="toggle-password fas fa-eye-slash"></i>
            </div>
            <input type="submit" name="signin" value="Login" class="btn solid" />
         </form>

          <form class="sign-up-form" method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <h2 class="title">Sign up</h2>
            <div class="input-field">
                <i class="fas fa-building"></i>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Insurance Name" name="insurance_name" required />
            </div>
            <div class="input-field">
                <i class="fas fa-users"></i>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Agent Full Name" name="full_name" required minlength="8" />
            </div>
            <div class="input-field">
                <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="username" required />
            </div>
            <div class="input-field">
                <i class="fas fa-envelope"></i>
                <input type="email" placeholder="Email" name="email" required />
            </div>
            <div class="input-field">
                <i class="fas fa-lock"></i>
                <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" required minlength="8" />
            </div>
            <input type="submit" name="signup" class="btn" value="Sign up" />
          </form>
```

Adding this to my settings.py is what I currently tried but still I cant access the main.html even though the username and password of the user(agent in this case) account in my database is exist and has an approved status:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
]`
```